# How to integrate $\frac{1+e^{x^{1/2}}}{1+e^{x}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $$\int \frac{1+e^{x^{1/2}}}{1+e^{x}}dx?$$

I am trying this question by writing the above expression as $$\int \frac{1}{1+e^{x}}dx + \int \frac{e^{x^{1/2}}}{1+e^{x}}dx.$$

Now I can easily integrate $$\int \frac{1}{1+e^{x}}dx$$ but I am facing problem to integrate $$\int \frac{e^{x^{1/2}}}{1+e^{x}}dx.$$

Please help me out with the proper solution.

Comment: [I'm not sure there is a closed form, unfortunately.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+%281%2Be%5E%28sqrt%28x%29%29%29%2F%281%2Be%5Ex%29)

Comment: From where you got this? I think I can do this if we have $e^{x/2}$ in $N^r$ instead of $e^{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @LuckyChouhan. Have fun ! It is a nice problem

Comment: As @LuckyChouhan pointed in comments (had it been $e^{\frac{x}{2}}$);
 
$$I=\int \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{1+e^x}\,dx$$

Put $e^\frac{x}{2}=t$,

$$I=\int \frac{2}{1+t^2}\,dt=2arctan(t)+c \implies I=2arctan(e^\frac{x}{2})+c$$

Answer (score 2):

For the second integral $$I=\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{1+e^x} \, dx$$ write it as
$$I=\int \Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-(n+1) x+\sqrt{x}}\Big)\,dx$$
$$J_n=\int  e^{-(n+1) x+\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2\int t\,e^{-(1+n)t^2 +t}\,dt$$ One integration by parts and completing the square
$$J_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, e^{\frac{1}{4 n+4}}}{2 (n+1)^{3/2}}\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{2 (n+1) t-1}{2 \sqrt{n+1}}\right)-\frac{e^{-(1+n)t^2 +t}}{n+1}$$

I do not see any way to go further.

If we consider
$$K_n=\int_0^\infty  e^{-(n+1) x+\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$
$$K_n=\frac 1{n+1}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{1}{4 n+4}}
   }{2 (n+1)^{3/2}}\left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{n+1}}\right)\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,K_n=\log(2)+\frac{\sqrt \pi}2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{ e^{\frac{1}{4 n+4}}
   }{ (n+1)^{3/2}}\left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{n+1}}\right)\right)$$

The convergence will be rather slow since
$$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=1-\frac{3}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$

Now, if you want to know how many terms have to be added, write
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,K_n=\sum_{n=0}^p (-1)^n\,K_n+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty (-1)^n\,K_n$$ and if you want
$$R_p \leq 10^{-k}\implies p\sim \sqrt[3]{ \frac{\pi}{4}   10^{2 k}}$$ that is to say $9227$ terms for $k=6$.

All of that to obtain the value of $2.08630$ given by numerical integration.